# Flow is not ending outside subgroup after rendering

Tags: mermaid

from the slightly changed examples this mermaid flow shows that the end is rendered inside subgroup.

```
flowchart TD
    A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
    B --> C{Let me think} --> z(END)
    C -->|One| D[Laptop] --> g1
    C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
    C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
    subgraph G
    g1(some) -- yes --> z
    end
```

how to change it to always have the end note beeing outside of subgroups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z(END)` is being included in the subgraph `G` because you've included it there:

```
subgraph G
g1(some) -- yes --> z
%%                  ^ here
end
```

It isn't entirely clear what you're going for, but if you move the connection between `g1` and `z` outside of the subraph, I think it will do what you want:

```html
<body>
  <pre class="mermaid">
    flowchart TD
        A[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)
        B --> C{Let me think} --> z(END)
        C -->|One| D[Laptop] --> g1
        C -->|Two| E[iPhone]
        C -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]
        subgraph G
            %% Just create g1 here
            g1(some)
        end

        %% And create the link outside of the subgraph
        g1 -- yes --> z
  </pre>

  <script type="module">
    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';
    mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
  </script>
</body>
```